# how to show DIB in silverlight for embedded application?

Tags: silverlight, windows-ce

I am new to silverlight, I'm working on a wince 6 camera application and I want use silverlight embedded as GUI, the data from camera is DIB format, so I test code like below, but the IXRBitmapImage is abstract class, can't be instantiated.

```
IXRImagePtr image;
IXRBitmapImagePtr source = new IXRBitmapImage();
if (FAILED(retcode=root->FindName(TEXT("MyImage"), &image)))
return -1;

source->SetBitmapSource(SHLoadDIBitmap(TEXT("/NandFlash/images/test.bmp")));
image->SetSource(source);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IXMBitmapImagePtr` are initialized through `IXRApplication->CreateObject(REFIID riid, IXRDependencyObject** ppObject) = 0;`

IXRApplication->CreateObject on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee503673%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx

For a tutorial:
http://geekswithblogs.net/WindowsEmbeddedCookbook/archive/2009/11/18/silverlight-for-windows-embedded-tutorial-step-3.aspx

Excerpt from the last link:
We declared two `IXRBitmapImagePtr` objects but we still haven't initialized them.
To create a Silverlight for Windows Embedded object we should use the CreateObject method of the IXRApplication object:

```
    if (FAILED(retcode=app->CreateObject(IID_IXRBitmapImage,&img01)))
          return retcode;
```